# Problem in using JQuery for body load event

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery(newbie for jquery) in my application. In short what I am doing: I have a home page, where user enters his name and gets results on the same page. So I wrote two functions in home.php , one for body load event another for getting user's result. I have "get_home_info.php" which will load on body's load event and get_info.php on button click event which will overwrite "get_home_info.php" and give user search results(i.e get_info.php).
  These functions are as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){        
            $('body').load($.get('/get_home_info.php', function(data){
            $('#get_data').html(data);
      })); 
    });
```

And another one for getting user result:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_submit").bind('click', function(){
        if($('#tnm').val() != '' && $('#tnm').val() != 'Enter a twitter username to know its Honest Followers!'){

        $('#loadimg').html('<img src="images/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
            $('#loadimg').show();       
            $.get('/get_info.php?tnm='+$('#tnm').val(), '', function(data){
                $('#get_data').html(data);
                 $('#loadimg').hide();  
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note: There are div tags in below code properly in body.
  Now my problem is that, I am not able to execute these two functions simultaneously, i.e when I comment bodyload function, and enter user name  I get result, and uncommenting body and trying username simply shows search result.

My question are :

1. can I write two function and execute these two functions at a time.
2. How can I give effects like on button's click event first page should disappear so that I can show loading image and after that result.

Can somebody help here please?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should place those two functions in 1 `$(document).ready(function(){});` and you can elemenate `$('body').load()` function because the `.load()` function is already an ajax call to a static html element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get('/get_home_info.php', function(data){ $('#get_data').html(data); });

    $("#btn_submit").bind('click', function(){
        if($('#tnm').val() != '' && $('#tnm').val() != 'Enter a twitter username to know its Honest Followers!'){

        $('#loadimg').html('<img src="images/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
            $('#loadimg').show();       
            $.get('/get_info.php?tnm='+$('#tnm').val(), '', function(data){
                $('#get_data').html(data);
                 $('#loadimg').hide();  
            });
        }
    });
});
```

you can get more definitions in the `.load()` function in [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

and `$.get()` in [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Thank you rob, just getting it done, was facing this problem from last two days and going to read these function carefully. thank you again for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try one $(document).ready block, so:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('body').load($.get('/get_home_info.php', function(data){
            $('#get_data').html(data);
  });
  $("#btn_submit").bind('click', function(){
        if($('#tnm').val() != '' && $('#tnm').val() != 'Enter a twitter username to know its Honest Followers!'){

        $('#loadimg').html('<img src="images/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
            $('#loadimg').show();       
            $.get('/get_info.php?tnm='+$('#tnm').val(), '', function(data){
                $('#get_data').html(data);
                 $('#loadimg').hide();  
            });
        }
    });
});
```